# Exception coming when exporting data to excel

Tags: .net, export-to-excel

I am getting following error while exporting data to excel sheet

```
ERROR:
Message : 
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Error Description : 
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Anybody suggest me what i have to do.

```
CODE:
gridData.dataSource = GetData()
gridData.DataBind()


Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",   "attachment;filename=CompletionDatesReport.xls")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
Dim stringWrite As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
Dim htmlWrite As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
gridData.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
Response.End()
```

Comment: the exception thrown is a **sql** exception; the code you have added tells us in the edit still tells us nothing about your db access. All we know is that `gridData` is involved in it somewhere.

Comment: In my code i bind record to DataGrid and then export data to excel sheet.In GetData() function using stored procedure i get data from Database.When i run stored procedure in Query Analyzer its ok but in my code given ERROR is coming.

Comment: Define "ok"... how long does it take?

Comment: 47 sec. to execute stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code we can only guess, but there is a big clue in the `SqlException: Timeout expired` - which suggests your query is taking too long. You can increase the timeout on a command (but try to keep it sane...) via `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`, but writing the query to be more efficient, or not pulling as much data in one query, would usually be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Marc. Have a look at your query and optimize it removing DISTINCT statements etc. to make it faster.